# Trying to oauth dropbox with Tornado Web

Tags: python, oauth, dropbox, tornado

Here is my mixin file:

```
import base64
import binascii
import hashlib
import hmac
import logging
import time
import urllib
import urlparse
import uuid
import tornado.web
import tornado.auth
from tornado import httpclient
from tornado import escape
from tornado.httputil import url_concat
from tornado.util import bytes_type, b

class DropboxMixin(tornado.auth.OAuthMixin):
    """ Dropbox  OAuth authentication.
    """
    _OAUTH_REQUEST_TOKEN_URL = "https://api.dropbox.com/1/oauth/request_token"
    _OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN_URL = "https://api.dropbox.com/1/oauth/access_token"
    _OAUTH_AUTHORIZE_URL = "https://www.dropbox.com/1/oauth/authorize"

    def authorize_redirect(self, callback_uri=None, extra_params=None,
                           http_client=None):
        """Redirects the user to obtain OAuth authorization for this service.

        Twitter and FriendFeed both require that you register a Callback
        URL with your application. You should call this method to log the
        user in, and then call get_authenticated_user() in the handler
        you registered as your Callback URL to complete the authorization
        process.

        This method sets a cookie called _oauth_request_token which is
        subsequently used (and cleared) in get_authenticated_user for
        security purposes.
        """
        if callback_uri and getattr(self, "_OAUTH_NO_CALLBACKS", False):
            raise Exception("This service does not support oauth_callback")
        if http_client is None:
            http_client = httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()
        http_client.fetch(
                          self._oauth_request_token_url(),
                          self.async_callback(
                                self._on_request_token, self._OAUTH_AUTHORIZE_URL,
                                callback_uri))

    def get_authenticated_user(self, callback, http_client=None):
        """Gets the OAuth authorized user and access token on callback.

        This method should be called from the handler for your registered
        OAuth Callback URL to complete the registration process. We call
        callback with the authenticated user, which in addition to standard
        attributes like 'name' includes the 'access_key' attribute, which
        contains the OAuth access you can use to make authorized requests
        to this service on behalf of the user.

        """
        request_key = escape.utf8(self.get_argument("oauth_token"))
        oauth_verifier = self.get_argument("oauth_verifier", None)
        request_cookie = self.get_cookie("_oauth_request_token")
        if not request_cookie:
            logging.warning("Missing OAuth request token cookie")
            callback(None)
            return
        self.clear_cookie("_oauth_request_token")
        cookie_key, cookie_secret = [base64.b64decode(escape.utf8(i)) for i in request_cookie.split("|")]
        if cookie_key != request_key:
            logging.info((cookie_key, request_key, request_cookie))
            logging.warning("Request token does not match cookie")
            callback(None)
            return
        token = dict(key=cookie_key, secret=cookie_secret)
        if oauth_verifier:
            token["verifier"] = oauth_verifier
        if http_client is None:
            http_client = httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()
        http_client.fetch(self._oauth_access_token_url(token),
                          self.async_callback(self._on_access_token, callback))

    def dropbox_request(self, path, callback, access_token=None,
                        post_args=None, **args):
        # Add the OAuth resource request signature if we have credentials
        url = "http://api.dropbox.com/1" + path
```

If anyone cares the url should read https://api.dropbox.com/1" + path

```
        if access_token:
            all_args = {}
            all_args.update(args)
            all_args.update(post_args or {})
            method = "POST" if post_args is not None else "GET"
            oauth = self._oauth_request_parameters(
                url, access_token, all_args, method=method)
            args.update(oauth)
        if args: url += "?" + urllib.urlencode(args)
        callback = self.async_callback(self._on_dropbox_request, callback)
        http = httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()
        if post_args is not None:
            http.fetch(url, method="POST", body=urllib.urlencode(post_args),
                       callback=callback)
        else:
            http.fetch(url, callback=callback)

    def _oauth_request_token_url(self, callback_uri= None, extra_params=None):
        consumer_token = self._oauth_consumer_token()
        url = self._OAUTH_REQUEST_TOKEN_URL
        args = dict(
            oauth_consumer_key=consumer_token["key"],
            oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",
            oauth_timestamp=str(int(time.time())),
            oauth_nonce=binascii.b2a_hex(uuid.uuid4().bytes),
            oauth_version=getattr(self, "_OAUTH_VERSION", "1.0"),
        )
        signature = _oauth_signature(consumer_token, "GET", url, args)

        args["oauth_signature"] = signature
        return url + "?" + urllib.urlencode(args)

    def _oauth_access_token_url(self, request_token):
        consumer_token = self._oauth_consumer_token()
        url = self._OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN_URL
        args = dict(
            oauth_consumer_key=consumer_token["key"],
            oauth_token=request_token["key"],
            oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",
            oauth_timestamp=str(int(time.time())),
            oauth_nonce=binascii.b2a_hex(uuid.uuid4().bytes),
            oauth_version=getattr(self, "_OAUTH_VERSION", "1.0"),
        )
        if "verifier" in request_token:
          args["oauth_verifier"]=request_token["verifier"]

        signature = _oauth_signature(consumer_token, "GET", url, args,
                                     request_token)

        args["oauth_signature"] = signature
        return url + "?" + urllib.urlencode(args)

    def _on_dropbox_request(self, callback, response):
        if response.error:
            print("Error response %s fetching %s", response.error,
                            response.request.url)
            callback(None)
            return
        callback(escape.json_decode(response.body))

    def _oauth_consumer_token(self):
        self.require_setting("dropbox_consumer_key", "Dropbox OAuth")
        self.require_setting("dropbox_consumer_secret", "Dropbox OAuth")
        return dict(
            key=self.settings["dropbox_consumer_key"],
            secret=self.settings["dropbox_consumer_secret"])

    def _oauth_get_user(self, access_token, callback):
        callback = self.async_callback(self._parse_user_response, callback)
        self.dropbox_request(
            "/account/info",
            access_token=access_token,
            callback=callback)

    def _oauth_request_parameters(self, url, access_token, parameters={},
                                  method="GET"):
        """Returns the OAuth parameters as a dict for the given request.

        parameters should include all POST arguments and query string arguments
        that will be sent with the request.
        """
        consumer_token = self._oauth_consumer_token()
        base_args = dict(
            oauth_consumer_key=consumer_token["key"],
            oauth_token=access_token["key"],
            oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",
            oauth_timestamp=str(int(time.time())),
            oauth_nonce=binascii.b2a_hex(uuid.uuid4().bytes),
            oauth_version=getattr(self, "_OAUTH_VERSION", "1.0"),
        )
        args = {}
        args.update(base_args)
        args.update(parameters)
        signature = _oauth_signature(consumer_token, method, url, args,
                                         access_token)
        base_args["oauth_signature"] = signature
        return base_args

    def _parse_user_response(self, callback, user):
        if user:
            user["username"] = user["display_name"]
        callback(user)

def _oauth_signature(consumer_token, method, url, parameters={}, token=None):
    """Calculates the HMAC-SHA1 OAuth signature for the given request.

    See http://oauth.net/core/1.0/#signing_process
    """
    parts = urlparse.urlparse(url)
    scheme, netloc, path = parts[:3]
    normalized_url = scheme.lower() + "://" + netloc.lower() + path

    base_elems = []
    base_elems.append(method.upper())
    base_elems.append(normalized_url)
    base_elems.append("&".join("%s=%s" % (k, _oauth_escape(str(v)))
                               for k, v in sorted(parameters.items())))
    base_string =  "&".join(_oauth_escape(e) for e in base_elems)

    key_elems = [escape.utf8(consumer_token["secret"])]
    key_elems.append(escape.utf8(token["secret"] if token else ""))
    key = b("&").join(key_elems)

    hash = hmac.new(key, escape.utf8(base_string), hashlib.sha1)
    return binascii.b2a_base64(hash.digest())[:-1]

def _oauth_escape(val):
    if isinstance(val, unicode):
        val = val.encode("utf-8")
    return urllib.quote(val, safe="~")


def _oauth_parse_response(body):
    p = escape.parse_qs(body, keep_blank_values=False)
    token = dict(key=p[b("oauth_token")][0], secret=p[b("oauth_token_secret")][0])

    # Add the extra parameters the Provider included to the token
    special = (b("oauth_token"), b("oauth_token_secret"))
    token.update((k, p[k][0]) for k in p if k not in special)
    return token
```

My View

```
class DropboxIndex(BaseHandler, DropboxMixin):
    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    def get(self):
        if self.get_argument("oauth_token", None):
            self.get_authenticated_user(self.async_callback(self._on_dbox_auth))
            return
        self.authorize_redirect()

    def _on_dbox_auth(self, token):
        from pprint import pprint
        pprint(token)
        self.redirect("/app/dropbox")
```

My URL Patterns

```
patterns = [
    (r"/", Index),
    (r"/help/?", Help),
    # User authentication
    (r"/user/login/?", Login),
    (r"/user/logout/?", LogoutHandler),
    (r"/user/edit/?", IdentityIndex),
    (r"/user/register/?", Register),
    (r"/user/twitter/auth/?", TwitterLogin),
    #(r"/user/google/auth/?", GoogleLogin),
    (r"/user/facebook/auth/?", FacebookLogin),
    (r"/app/dropbox/?", DropboxIndex),
    (r"/app/dropbox/account/?", DropboxAccount),
    (r"/social/?", SocialIndex),
    (r"/api/tweets/?", apiSocialTweets),
    (r"/media/(.*)", tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, {"path" : static_serve}), 
]
```

Everything works except being brought back to my callback uri with the oauth_token. I see the oauth_token in the query and can authorize my app with dropbox.. i just can't get the oauth_token back and usuable

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is a pretty huge piece of code to spend time on, so excuse me if my answer doesn't help much -

Urllib / Urllib2 are pretty much incompatible with handling asynchronous requests. You can follow up [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119680/multiple-asynchronous-connections-with-urllib2-or-other-http-library) question to know why and the solution if you have to use urllib.

What I would suggest is to use httplib instead in your code, do comment if this helps or you want to know more.

Thanks
Sushant